# Problems running jQuery in Quickbase

Tags: jquery, quickbase

I'm trying to get jQuery to run on Quickbase.  I've run this code in jsfiddle and it works fine.  It's really simple code to test out the html pages in Quickbase.  I am currently using the built in html pages option and adding the code below but the scripting does not work.  What am I missing?

```
<style>
.test{
color:blue;
}
</style>

<body>
<h1 class="test">
test
</h1>

<div id="mydiv"></div> 

<script type="text/ javascript">
var version = $().jquery;
$("#mydiv").html("QuickBase is using jQuery version " + version);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('h1').css('border','solid 2px red');
});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you actually including jQuery in your code as well?

Comment: The only code I'm entering is above.  According to the documentation and the few forums I can find about this I do not need to call in the jQuery library as it built in.  I'll give that a try though.  Just in case.

Comment: Yeah you could also check the final source output of your test page, which should include a reference to jQuery.

Comment: Against all documentation and advice, including jQuery made it work.  I appreciate the help.  Now I need to figure out how to get PHP to work in this beast.

Comment: Glad the jQuery works. Good luck with the PHP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though QuickBase says that jQuery is on by default in the code pages that can be built you will still have to call it in each page should you need it.